# Regex match non-alpha character except hyphen for compound word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

Regex for python 3.6. I'm trying to remove non-alpha characters but i would like to not match hyphen in compound word. Here is my pattern :

```
[^\sA-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF\u0153\u0152-]|(?=\W)-(?<=\W)
```

For example for `- word-word` i would like to match the first - but non the second one but my pattern matches both.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Could you provide examples of correct and actual output?

Comment: Edited sorry, python 3.6 and i put an example

Comment: But your `[^\sA-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF\u0153\u0152-]` is not matching all non-alphanumeric chars, what are you really doing? Well, I think you want something like https://regex101.com/r/7XROxc/1

Comment: Also, try [`re.sub(r'([^\W\d_]-)(?=[^\W\d_])|(?:[^\w\s]|_)', r'\1', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/7XROxc/2)

Comment: oh yes sorry it's non-alpha only. Thanks for your link, could you explain what is \1 ? why does it match the 'd' of the first 'word' ?

Comment: See some variations of the regexps in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.6, you may use a technique to *match and capture* what you need to keep (a `-` in between letters can be matched with `[^\W\d_]-(?=[^\W\d_])`) and just match what you need to remove (all the non-alphanumeric or whatever characters you define).

So, an example `re.sub` will look like

```
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_]-)(?=[^\W\d_])|[^\sA-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF\u0153\u0152]', r'\1', s)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_]-)(?=[^\W\d_])|(?:[^\w\s]|_)', r'\1', s)
```

where

- `([^\W\d_]-)(?=[^\W\d_])` - any letter and `-` followed with any letter (it is in a positive lookahead to allow consecutive matches, like `a-b-c`)
- `|` - or
- `(?:[^\w\s]|_)` - any single non-word and non-whitespace char or `_` is matched.

The `r'\1'` is a replacement backreference, a placeholder referring to the contents in Group 1 that inserts it back to the resulting string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7XROxc/2).

In Python versions before 3.5, you will need to use a lambda as the replacement argument to check if Group 1 matched:

```
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_]-)(?=[^\W\d_])|(?:[^\w\s]|_)', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', s)
```

Another possible solution is

```
re.sub(r'(?!\b-\b)(?:[^\w\s]|_)', '', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7XROxc/3). Here, `-` enclosed with word chars will not be matched as `\b` word boundaries are used (but it will avoid matching  `-` even when enclosed with underscores).

Comment: For the last solution, just to be sure, to begin with a negative lookahead (which is normally for me at the right of another pattern), you're avoid to place the "regex cursor" just before an hyphen before continuing with the rest of the pattern ?

Comment: @TmSmth `(?!\b-\b)` restricts the `(?:[^\w\s]|_)` pattern, it makes it match what it can match but a `-` within word boundaries.